# Vue router-link exact active class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a 3 of menu tabs (i.e. `router-link`s) that correspond to 3 different routes:

```
/        --> home
/users   --> users
/posts   --> posts
```

The first `router-link` going to `/` has the `exact` property applied, so it does not receive an active class when on `/users` or `/posts`.  This works for most cases, however I am planning on allowing query parameters on the `/` route.  For example:

```
/?ref=producthunt
```

In this case, the `/` `router-link` should still be active.  However, given I have the `exact` property on it, it is not matching the url with the `ref` query parameter.  Outside of adding additional logic to my component to test the route and flip classes, is there some feature of the `router-link` component I can use to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use router-link to navigate to '/' with the ref query parameter, why not just set `ref` as a query property in `router-link`? It will still work with `exact`.

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/', query: { ref: 'producthunt' } }" exact>home</router-link>
```

Check [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/qj53veyy/).

**Updated**
If you are talking about `vue-router`'s setting issues, I think url like `http://example.com/?ref=producthunt` will be automatically directed to the home component without any advanced configuration because there's no parameter like `exact` in its api (I tried in a vuejs2+webpack project built by vue-cli just now). If it wasn't directed to your home, I wonder if there's anything wrong in other places like server application's configuration.

Comment: Hm, that would work, but that's not how I want to use `ref`.  I want the `router-link` to remain exactly how it is.  I only want the query param set to `producthunt` when the user navigates to my web app via Product Hunt.  :)

Comment: @sir_thursday Hi, I'm sorry but I still cannot get your idea very well. To my understanding, your website's link on the internet followed with `ref` parameter clicked, the user should still be navigated to your home, as well as the link without this parameter. Am I right?

Comment: I don't want the `?ref=producthunt` to be shown if the user navigates to Home via the `router-link`, because the user was not referred by Product Hunt, they were referred by my own internal link.  Thus, I cannot have the `query` parameter set on the `router-link`, as you suggested.  Does this help?

Comment: @sir_thursday Yes, thanks. Actually I already knew my answer didn't meet your requirement. I just tried to confirm whether I understood your first comment since I don't see `exact` works beyond `router-link`'s context. Since characters are limited in comment, I'll append my thought in the answer. Wish it made sense to you.